# Need select option by another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have two inputs one is simple input another is select input with options. How can i achieve that when someone enters value for text input it automatically select correct option.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-2">
  <label class="text-black" for="test2">Job code</label>
  <input type="text" id="test2" name="jobcode[]" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Job</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="job[]" >
      <option value="1">Administrator - 1</option>
      <option value="2">Bartender - 2</option>
      <option value="3">Mechanic - 3</option>
      <option value="4">Bodybuilder - 4</option>
      <option value="5">Doctor- 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, here the code simply checks if the inputted value is among the options available and changes the selected option to the one whose value is the same as what was entered in the input element.

```js
var test2 = document.getElementById("test2")
var test3 = document.querySelector("[name=job]")

test2.onchange = () => {
  if ([...test3.children].some(each => each.value == test2.value)) {
    test3.value = test2.value
  }else{
    test3.value = 1
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04b00d367c.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-black" for="test2">Job code</label>
    <input type="text" id="test2" name="jobcode[]" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="text-black" for="padalinys">Job</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="job">
      <option value="1">Administrator - 1</option>
      <option value="2">Bartender - 2</option>
      <option value="3">Mechanic - 3</option>
      <option value="4">Bodybuilder - 4</option>
      <option value="5">Doctor- 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well quite nice solution but would be great if he change live and when empty exchange to start value.

Comment: That's simple to do with an `else` statement

Comment: and what if i have adding dynamically inputs in the same form with the same names. But i wanna that they change one by one.

Comment: Give them unique `id`s and change the code use id's instead on name, I used name here because that's what's available

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(function($) {
  $('#test2').on('blur', function(e) {
    let inputVal = $(this).val();

    $('#select option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === inputVal) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Here I get the inserted value at the `input` field on `blur` event. And check each option of the select if the value of the option is same as the input field's value. If so then change the `selected prop` of the `option`.